# how to give standard input to slice a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, stdin

Trying to slice dataframe by choosing particular value of column :

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})

mask = df['A'] == 'foo'

df[mask]
```

This retrieves the perfect solution

```
 A       B  C   D  
foo    one  0   0   
foo    two  2   4   
foo    two  4   8   
foo    one  6  12   
foo  three  7  14
```

But when trying to give value with standard input function...I am getting a empty dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8), 'D': np.arange(8) * 2})

mask = df['A'] == input("enter: ")
```

enter: 'foo'

```
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame     
Columns: [A, B, C, D]      
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try removing quotes if using Python 3**

I python 2.7 
I entered 'foo' (with quotes).. And it was working

But in python 3.6 it was not working.
I removed the quotes and entered foo. Now its working

Comment: In python 3 input() works like raw_input() of python 2. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: Yes, @jimmy It is working without the quotes. Thanks for helping out : )